# Redirect joomla login to page with parameters in URL

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I have a custom login page. When the user logs in, I want to redirect the user to a page with extra parameters in the URL. Currently I can set the redirect page in the parameters of the module, but I can't set any parameters which i can pass to the redirect.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix it like so:

I created a new folder `mod_login` in the root of the template i'm using. There I added a copied and pasted the original `default.php` view file and renamed it to something else.

I then searched for the hidden `input` with `name="return"`.

Eventually I changed the value like so:

`<input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo base64_encode(JURI::base() . 'page?parameter=value'); ?>" />`

Comment: I agree with your solution, but I would like to note that in Joomla 3.2 it is also possible to override the mod_login by using the template manager in Joomla. It is easier to do it that way, instead of manually copying.

Comment: I didn't mention that this was for 2.5